# Access to online features while System Software: Version 4.55 is downloading?

Tags: ps4

I woke up to find that version 4.55 had come out. From a source I have been told that it “improves the quality of the system performance.” So that was all fine, as the update was only 340 MB not much to worry about and then I realized that I had access to online features. This had never happened to me before, and what I would like to know is:

- Is my PS4 in danger?
- Is this a fault of Sony or a glitch, or was it meant to happen?
- Is anyone else getting this behaviour ?

  I had additional questions but I forgot. I will update the question with an edit if I remember.

Comment: So you normally do not have access to online features? I mean, is your PS4 usually disconnected from the internet or something?

Comment: @Nzall No the way PS4 works (for me) is that when it is downloading an update I can't play online or join parties or anything. And when it updates I can

Comment: From what I can tell from some quick googling, you could always have played online, but you needed your account settings to be in order: configured a primary account with autologin. maybe you changed something else?

Comment: @Nzall normally the PS4 doesn't allow you to go online if you don't have the most recent firmware version. I'm pretty sure it does that from the moment the new firmware is out, though I don't know if it has to download the file first (because not having online access might restrict that). I'd check my PS4, but I won't be able to till later, hopefully someone can check right now, though I don't think it's a danger to your PS4.

Comment: @Nzall Well recently I activated my ps4 as primary (I got hacked a few months ago) . Might be what your talking about.

Comment: @FFHannibal I'm talking about the discussion at https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/3t5cci/why_does_my_ps4_never_seem_to_download_updates_in/cx3ed04/. > *Make sure your profile is set as the primary profile for the console. If it is not activated as the primary updates won't download, cloud saves won't upload automatically, etc.*

Comment: @Nzall yeah, but I'm pretty sure it's the PS4 having outdated firmware that blocks the online until you update, not the fact that your account isn't the primary account. Also your account doesn't have to be primary to have cloud saves etc. work, you can adjust those things in the settings regardless of what kind of account yours is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in a comment, you recently set your profile in your PS4 as the primary profile. According to https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/3t5cci/why_does_my_ps4_never_seem_to_download_updates_in/cx3ed04/, some features don't work if you don't have a primary profile defined.

> Make sure your profile is set as the primary profile for the console. If it is not activated as the primary updates won't download, cloud saves won't upload automatically, etc.

In addition, like FFHannibal mentioned in a comment, the PS4 does not allow you to go online with outdated firmware. Why you were able to use the online features this time is unclear.

Comment: Well when  my ps4 was not primary I could download updates and stuff. But now I can play while its downloading. good answer but I dont think it answers my actual question : ) . +1

Answer (score 3):

I think there is some general confusion on the part of the OP, so I will do my best to explain Sony's update process.

When a system update is pushed out, this time being 4.55, the user is notified of this update once they turn their console on. While the update is available, the user cannot go online to PSN; they cannot see their friends, trophies and other data will not sync, and the user cannot participate in multiplayer games. As was mentioned in some comments on the OP, this is to make sure all users are online with the same firmware, to avoid any mix-ups with online play.

As far as I know, it has nothing to do with having an account assigned as the primary account, nor does it have anything to do with having your PS4 as the primary console.

There are two possible updates for firmware. Non-critical firmware updates are simple bug fixes or UI changes; as the description of this update stated, it was for minor fixes. For more major firmware updates, like 4.00 or 4.50, network connectivity features are disabled while the update downloads.

So, to answer your questions in short:

- No, your PS4 is fine.
- It is a by design process.
- It happens to me for each update.

Comment: Great answer. As mentioned I made a few comments about it, but I had some difficulty formulating an actual answer. You managed to do it in a clear and concise manner. +1

Comment: `While the update is available, the user cannot go online to PSN; they cannot see their friends, trophies and other data will not sync, and the user cannot participate in multiplayer games.` I don't think you understood my question. I did actually have access to online features while the update was downloading. Usually, when I am downloading an update I have to wait for it to install and then I have access to online. But this time I could play with friends while the update was downloading meaning that I was playing on a different firmware as them.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket answer amended. I forgot about that part.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Ah thank you. I was unaware that minor updates did not conflict with online features. Thank you.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket This was introduced with firmware 4 I believe, whenever the new UI came out that allowed folders and such. At least as far as I know, this was the first time I started seeing minor updates like this.

Comment: Ha. The answer to my question about firmware was answered by an update about firmware.